# Database error. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting this error:

> An error occured: Database error. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com, `salt` = , `iteration` = 12, `method` = blowfish, `person_id`' at line 1

Here is the code:

```
$data_con = new data_abstraction;
$data_con->execute_query("INSERT into `USER` SET `username` = $user, `password` = $phsh, `email` = $email, `salt` = $salt, `iteration` = $new_iteration, `method` = $new_method, `person_id` = $result2, `role_id` = $result4, `skin_id` = $result5");
```

Edit:

I already used prepared the query, used parameterized statements and bind the parameters. The error has gone but the details I want to be inserted into the table are not added.

Here is my code:

```
if(!($sql = $link->prepare("INSERT into `USER` SET 
                                    `username`  = ?, 
                                    `password`  = ?, 
                                    `email`     = ?, 
                                    `salt`      = ?, 
                                    `iteration` = ?, 
                                    `method`    = ?, 
                                    `person_id` = ?, 
                                    `role_id`   = ?, 
                                    `skin_id`   = ?"))){
                                        echo "SQL Query Preparation has failed";
                                    }

                    if(!($sql->bind_param("ssssisiii", $user, $phsh, $email, $new_salt, $new_iteration, $new_method, $result2, $result4, $result5))){
                        echo "Parameter Binding failed";
                    }

                    if(!($sql->execute())){
                        echo "MySQL Query Execution has failed";
                    }
```

Comment: INSERT INTO USER (username,password) values($user,$password);

Comment: @RiggsFolly i am sorry i think that its a insert. but he mixing :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24324636/1064-you-have-an-error-in-your-sql-syntax-check-the-manual-that-corresponds)

Comment: @LifeTimeProgrammer No my mistake, I always forget you can use SET in a INSERT

Answer (score 1):

All text data must be wrapped in quotes in a concatenated query like this. It is also legal to wrap integers in quotes so its safer to do both like this

```
$data_con = new data_abstraction;
$data_con->execute_query("INSERT into `USER` SET 
            `username`  = '$user', 
            `password`  = '$phsh', 
            `email`     = '$email', 
            `salt`      = '$salt', 
            `iteration` = '$new_iteration', 
            `method`    = '$new_method', 
            `person_id` = '$result2', 
            `role_id`   = '$result4', 
            `skin_id`   = '$result5'");
```

It would be better to use a parameterised query like this and then bind the values

```
$sql = "INSERT into `USER` SET 
                `username`  = ?, 
                `password`  = ?, 
                `email`     = ?, 
                `salt`      = ?, 
                `iteration` = ?, 
                `method`    = ?, 
                `person_id` = ?, 
                `role_id`   = ?, 
                `skin_id`   = ?");
```

And then [prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) the query and  bind the values to the `?` using [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

This will also protect you from [SQL Injection Attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: what is the use for insert query with `SET ` and without `SET`? shot ans sweet and +1

Comment: @LifeTimeProgrammer Sorry cannot answer that, its legal syntax, but I have never used it myself, which is why it always trips me up when I see it and my first though is always that it is incorrect syntax

Answer (score -1):

`$email` contains special character so quote email column value `email` `= '$email'`

Comment: That is true, but the OP is also using some sort of database handler, so it might fix that for him. Since I'm not familiar with execute_query() and the data_abstraction class, I have no idea what that does (but yes, I also missed the obvious error).

Comment: @RiggsFolly are you sure? did you checked it or just commented and given minus rating in my comment?

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie are you sure? did you checked it or just commented and given minus rating in my comment?

Comment: Sorry, always forget you can use SET in an INSERT, it gets me every time. Brain hiccup

Answer (score -1):

You need to wrap each $variable in single quotes ''. BTW, that is horrible code, unless the execute_query() method sanitizes those input variables. If it doesn't, you seriously need to take a look at parameterizing your queries. I'm assuming you use mysqli? If so, take a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php